# for + noun/pronoun + infinitive

Tags: infinitives, for

Given

> The aim is that we should learn English in six months.

I need to use *for + noun/pronoun + infinitive* to rewrite it, but I couldn't do it.

My attempts were

> 1. *The aim for us is to learn English in six months*
> 2. *For us to learn English is we should in six months.*

but I'm not using *should* in the first one and I don't know if my second attempt is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *The aim is* and *English in six months* can be held constant in both versions.
2. Then it's simply a matter of transforming

   > **that** Subject<sup>**subject** case</sup>(=**we**) learn<sup>'subjunctive'</sup>(=**should learn**)
   > *into*
   >  **for** Subject<sup>**object** case</sup>(=**us**)    learn<sup>infinitive</sup>(=**to learn**)

This yields:

> The aim is for us to learn English in six months.

Comment: Nice. I thought the modal needed to be used in the sentence anyway.

Comment: what if I make the sentence in this way , would it be correct?

For us to learn English in six months is the aim.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**: **"The aim is for us to learn English in six months"** is clear and correct. [Aside: that is an unrealistic expectation of your students; English can be quite difficult, even for native speakers.]

**"For us to learn English is we should in six months"** is ungrammatical, just as as you suspected. "Should" implies an expectation, which as I said above, is unrealistic. Posed as a question, the answer might be, **"Is it realistic to expect us to learn English in six months?"**

Comment: His first sentence is clear, but not correct for the requirements of the assignment. The assignment asks for the construction to be for + pronoun + infinitive...he has for + pronoun + is + infinitive...

Comment: @AlexK- You are correct! Is my edited answer better?

Comment: Yes, that is correct